# Is there a way to get to a phones texting interface throught a link button? Using J Query Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, sms

Is there a way to get to a phones texting interface once a button is clicked? Using J Query Mobile.

I know you can make a link button to email an email address with mailto: or call someone by using tel: but is there a way to open a users texting interface specifically IOS phone or tablet to a specific phone number or contact from a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the OS support but on my phone with Android 2.3 when I setup a link with a `sms` protocol then it opens my text messaging interface when I click the link.

For Example:

```
<a href="sms:5555555555">Text Now</a>
```

Also, I believe that PhoneGap can expose the text messaging interface on a phone programatically.

Comment: Phonegap doesn't have any built-in SMS support - you can get support by using a plugin.
Also, Windows Phone 7 doesn't support the "sms:" urls.  You have to create the SmsComposeTask in a plugin instead.